# Redis server version for RedisToGo on Heroku

Tags: heroku, redistogo

I am using the RedisToGo add-on on heroku.

How can I get the redis server version being used?

Answer (score 3):

Using the `INFO` command in redis-cli will give this information.

For my situation: In my rails app have a constant called `REDIS` that is initialized as a Redis client. Doing a `REDIS.info` gave me the required information.

Comment: glad to hear you figured this one out!

Comment: @gagan: how did you run redis-cli on Heroku

Answer (score 1):

They [say explicitly](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/redistogo#redis-2-8) on their site:

> All new RedisToGo instances run with 2.8.9 as default. If you have an
>   existing instance and need your version upgrading then please drop us
>   a line and we’ll get you set up.