# How can I find the version for Heroku's Redis add-on version?

Tags: heroku, redis, heroku-toolbelt

We run a Redis add-on on Heroku and I'd like to define the same version in a Puppet provisioning step. Heroku doesn't seem to expose Redis version information anywhere, though. I've tried:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-add-ons
- The add-on's 'Settings' page

I would prefer not to discover this information programmatically like this [question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21742051/redis-server-version-for-redistogo-on-heroku).

Comment: Using INFO command is a precise way of finding your server's Redis version.

Comment: @Niloct OP specifically says they do not want to use the INFO command.

Comment: @Eli the underlying question embedded on my comment was, why not use the command ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with using RedisToGo as in the question you linked to, the information is [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/redistogo#redis-2-8):

> All new RedisToGo instances run with 2.8.9 as default. If you have an
>   existing instance and need your version upgrading then please drop us
>   a line and we’ll get you set up.

Comment: Thanks for finding that - I came across that information but was unable to verify if Heroku uses the same version for their 'vanilla' Redis add-on. Do you know?